# How to make tokenize not treat contractions and their counter parts as the same when comparing two text files?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, cs50, sentence-similarity

I am currently working on a data structure that is supposed to compare two text files and make a list of the strings they have in common. my program receives the content of the two files as two strings a & b (one file's content per variable). I then use the tokenize function in a for loop to break the string by each sentence. They are then stored into a set to avoid duplicate entries. I remove all duplicate lines within each variable before I compare them. I then compare each the two variables to each other and only keep the string they have in common. I have a bug that occurs in the last part when they are comparing against each other. The program will treat contractions and their proper counter parts as the same when it should not. For Example it will read Should not and Shouldn't as the same and will produce an incorrect answer. I want to make it not read contraction and their counter parts as the same.

```
import nltk

def sentences(a, b): #the variables store the contents of the files in the form of strings
 a_placeholder = a
 set_a = set()
 a = []
 for punctuation_a in nltk.sent_tokenize(a_placeholder): 
  if punctuation_a not in set_a:
   set_a.add(punctuation_a)
   a.append(punctuation_a)

 b_placeholder = b
 set_b = set()
 b = []
 for punctuation_b in nltk.sent_tokenize(b_placeholder):
  if punctuation_b not in set_b:
   set_b.add(punctuation_b)
   b.append(punctuation_b)

 a_new = a
 for punctuation in a_new:
  if punctuation not in set_b:
   set_a.remove(punctuation)
   a.remove(punctuation)
  else:
   pass

 return []
```

Comment: `make a list of the strings they have in common`: does it mean `string_from_file_1 == string_from_file_2`? If so, you don't need NLTK preprocessing, common string comparisons would do. Can you post a few lines from each file and an example of the expected output?